# Enscroll js scrollbar sits outside the container

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar, margin

I have a container with an unordered list. The container has margin properties set as `auto auto 5em`.

On adding scrollbar to the container using enscroll js, the scrollbar is absolutely positioned without considering the `container` position.

JSFiddle is at, http://jsfiddle.net/madhavan020985/tmt4phuv/4/

By removing the margin properties for `container`, it is rendered properly. 
But i need to align the container to the center using `margin`.

Issue caused by,

```
#container{        
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 5em;
}
```

Comment: difficult to say without seeing css for enscroll. but can't u set margin-left and margin-top for enscroll as a test

Comment: yes, i too feel i need to read how enscroll.js is written.. a tough task.. in btw, adding margin to enscroll is an ugly hack since synchronising the margins for scrollbar and container takes a lot of effort....

Comment: just out of curiosity whey you went for this; slimscroll is widely used for such req.

Comment: oh, is it...will take a look at it....

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy fix for this (altough i agree with others that you should've shared enscroll without minimizing it). Just wrap the container in another container, and margin that one. As such:[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qfydLsd/)

```
<div id="biggercontainer">
    <div id="container">
     ...
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#biggercontainer{

  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 5em;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
#container{

  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, the fiddle stops working when i fork it, probably something going wrong with enscroll there, but it works when i make the changes on your fiddle

Comment: was an issue with https/http mixup, new fiddle should work